# Counting one dimensional random walks with boundaries

Tags: combinatorics, random-walk

I was able to find plenty of literature on counting the number of symmetric random walks of `n` steps starting at the origin and ending at `m` without crossing the origin.

Is there a succinct or otherwise efficient method to enumerate how many of these walks also do not cross a specific upper boundary?

I'm hoping for a formula or sum that's not inclusion-exclusion (since I think I'd be fairly comfortable determining a recurrence).